# OCR android application does not work in Sunmi V2 plus device

Tags: java, android, ocr

I'm building an OCR android application by using google vision API but when I run it on Sunmi V2 plus device, it does not work , they tell me to first enable google play services while the device does not have google play services. so, the problem I have, is there an other way I can build OCR application and run it on Sunmi V2 plus device? or How can I enable google play services on Sunmi V2 plus device?

[that is how my build looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr4Nj.png)

```
  <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
```

```
textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {
            }
            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                SparseArray<TextBlock> items = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if (items.size() != 0 ){

                    mTextView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                                TextBlock item = items.valueAt(i);
                                stringBuilder.append(item.getValue());
                                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                            }
                            mTextView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                            
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```